# Make a grid expand to remaining height inside a flex item

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

There are lots of similar questions, I have reviewed all of them, but none solved my problem.

**Premises:**
I have a flexbox layout with `flex column` and the bottom flex-item filling the remainder of the page height. The flex-item gets stretched to the remainder of the page by `flex 1`.

**Goal:**
I need my grid (with its children) inside this flex-item to expand to the height of the flex-item.

**Problem:**
The html wrapper only has a `min-height 100vh` set. This makes the grid stretch to the flex-item, but not its children!

The only solution I can find is to also set `height 100vh` on the html wrapper, but I do not want to do this. Is there any way to solve my problem without setting `height`?

See the codepen here: 
https://codepen.io/mesqueeb/pen/aGeKjm

See the animated GIF here to show you what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

remove the `flex-direction: column;` in the `.remaining` and it will expand the height.

```css
main{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 51px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div{
    border: solid goldenrod thick;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
}
.full-page{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}
.top-row{
    height: 100px;
}
.remaining{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}
.grid{
    border: solid teal thick;
    flex: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.key{
    border: thin green solid
}
.small{
    font-size: .8em
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="full-page">
        <div class="top-row">
            grid below will take full height only if body height is set...
        </div>
        <div class="remaining">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="key">1</div>
                <div class="key">2</div>
                <div class="key">3</div>
                <div class="key">4</div>
                <div class="key">5</div>
                <div class="key">6</div>
                <div class="key">7</div>
                <div class="key">8</div>
                <div class="key">9</div>
                <div class="key">C</div>
                <div class="key">0</div>
                <div class="key">➕</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it solves your problem in the best way, but this works:

```
.remaining {
    flex: 1;
   /* display: flex; */
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
.grid {
    border: solid #008080 thick;
/* flex: 1; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also a great answer, but I decided to go with davecar's answer because making the grid absolute and forcing me to make the parent relative gives me some complications when it comes to other absolute items that originally needed the grand-parent to be relative. (kind of hard to explain, but some also overflow related etc. so absolute is just too big of an affect on the other elements in my setup.) thanks anyway!